# Как создать репозиторий с кучей папок-проектов внутри

Tags: github, project

У меня есть одна корневая папка (неплохо бы её сделать репозиторием), а в ней создаются разные подпроекты, в своих подпапках. их может добавляться/изменяться много. Пример структуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне правильно организовать такое в репозиториях гитхаба (как понимаю обычно подразумевается что один реп - один проект), а мне нужна группа папок где каждая - проект. Какие команды использовать.. Ну и соотвественно как закинуть всё это скопом в гитхаб, чтобы и папки(струткура паопок) тоже в github посоздавалась, и потом добавлять новый проект как подпапку?

Если просто для файла, то как понимаю нужна примерно такая последовательность команд:

```
1) git init  
2) git add . or git add ['filename']  
3) git commit -m "My first Files"  
4) git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git  
5) git pull origin master 
   или git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories  
6) git push -u origin master
   или git push -f origin master
```

но мне надо целые проекты в своих папках подобавлять

С уважением, Геннадий

Comment: верно - один реп - один проект

Comment: у меня одна вебчасть каждые пару дней.. неужто под каждую создавать свой отдельный реп?

Comment: При желании все можно запихнуть и в один большой проект, но ничего хорошего это не сулит. В интернете уже много сказано про проблемы монорепозиториев.

Comment: Если пытаюсь через github desktop/клонировать, потом папку добросить то изменения видны, но после коммита новых папок не вижу

Comment: @user7860670 понятно... я понял ваш ответ! спасибо большое!